# Log out of Session - Python

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I'm trying to set up a python `requests.Session` to log in to a site and do something. I was able to get the log in working, however whenever the loop closes, the Session remains logged in. I've tried using a context manager, I've manually called `Session.close`, but I can still make requests logged into the site. What should I do so the session won't be able to get information from the secure account.

```py
from requests import Session

with Session() as session:
    session.post(login_url, data=login_data)
    home_page = session.get(home_page_url)  # Everything works

home_page2 = session.get(home_page_url)  # Still gets the home page even though it should be logged out
print(home_page2.text)
```

Comment: I figured out I can call the logout link, but I'm still wondering if there's a built-in way to logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a child class of Session that would handle automatically logging in and out as part of its ContextManager.

```py
class Login(Session):
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        super().__init__()
        self.login(email, password)

    def login(self, email, password):
        self.post(login_url, data={"user":email,"pass":password})

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.get(logout_url)
        super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)


with Login(email, password) as login:
    login.get(home_page_url)
login.get(home_page_url)  # Logged out
```